# How to know is which archive page is active

Tags: wordpress

I create two custom post type name as 'product' and 'blog'. I also create two archive page name as 'archive-product.php' and 'archive-blog.php'.

Now i want to know which page is active. example we know is_page('contact') if page is contact then it return true. So is there any way or function to know is this archive page 'product' or 'blog'

Thanks

Comment: Set 2 different echos in the two pages (archives), and see what the differences from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this wherever you need to know which category is displayed:

```
<?php get_the_category(); ?>
```

Default is `$post->ID` but you can throw whatever post ID you need to return the relevant category.

In this case, try

```
$category = get_the_category();
switch ($category[0]->cat_name){
  case 'product':
    //do whatever
  break;
  case 'blog':
    //do whatever
  break;
  default:
    //do whatever
  break;
}
```

See [WP codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) for more info.

Comment: but archive page has multiple post